# Angular - Routes get parameter in When

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app i only want a user to be able to go to the story page if the id of the page they are visiting is valid.

To implement this I believe (correct me if there is a simpler way) i need to work on the routes. However how do i pass the `:id` into my method within `usefulService`:

```
.when("/story/:id",
    {
      templateUrl: "views/story.html",
      controller: 'Story' ,
      controllerAs: 'story',
      resolve:{
        "check":function($location, usefulService){
            if(!usefulService.isRealID(id)){ //here is where I want to pass id
                $location.path('/');
            }
        }
      }
    }
)
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `$route`:

```
.when("/story/:id", {
    templateUrl : "views/story.html",
    controller : 'Story',
    controllerAs : 'story',
    resolve : {
        "check" : function ($location, $route, usefulService) {
            if (!usefulService.isRealID($route.current.pathParams.id)) { //here is where I want to pass id
                $location.path('/');
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Ahhh! Great that works. Obvious when you see ! Thank you!

Comment: And would you agree this is the best way to do this - a user to be able to go to the story page if the id of the page they are visiting is valid

Comment: Yep, I use this all the time in my own application.